# Error: "Reason: image not found" when setting up C++ SFML for Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

I am very close to finally getting C++ programming to work with SFML on my macOS. I went to a camp that only used Windows computers to program and I have been struggling to get C++ with SFML to work at my home. So I have been watching tutorials about how to get C++ with SFML to work on Xcode, and I recieve the following error after doing setting it all up:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-window.2.5.dylib
  Referenced from: 
/Users/David/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML_Proj.- 
  hadjgrdxcbtqnjejwvchenudpkqr/Build/Products/Debug/SFML Proj.
  Reason: image not found
```

I have tried to fix it by looking at comments that say to put brew install sfml into terminal, but the following error shows up.

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `brew: command not found` looks like you don't have `brew` installed or its not in your PATH

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148901/why-does-my-brew-installation-not-work